# sum function and count function in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query question related to count function and sum function.

### I got a data which has two columns, one is tasker_id and another is hire ("1" is hired, "0" is not), same ID can hired multiple times, the data looks like below:

```
Takser_ID     hire
   1           1
   2           0
   1           1
   3           0
   4           1
   2           1
   1           1
   5           0
   3           0
   2           1
   8           0
      ...
```

Since the value of hire is 0 and 1, so if I want to find out how many times for each tasker_ID got hired, I should get the same answer if I use count () function or Sum() function. 
The SQL queries was shown below:

For count ():

```
select tasker_id, count(hired) as count_hired
from test.test
group by tasker_id
order by count_hired;
```

For Sum():

```
select tasker_id, sum(hired) as sum_hired
from test.test
group by tasker_id
order by sum_hired;
```

However, the results were totally different. From the result, the sum function seems right, because I can get some Tasker_ID user who actually have 0 hired.
But, for count () function, there were no cases who have 0 hired, and the results seems wired.

Is there anyone who can help me with that? What is wrong???

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count simply count the number of not null value in your rows

so in your case  you have a count that is exactly the number of rows  related to your tasker_id

you could have a correct count result if instead of 0  you have null

you could also get  a value using a sum for case eg:

```
select 
   tasker_id
 , sum(hired) as sum_hired
 , sum(case when hired= 0 then 1  else 0 end ) not_hired_count
from test.test
group by tasker_id
order by sum_hired;
```

Answer (score 0):

For your count query you are including rows where hired = 0, which I assume you would not want to. The sum is excluding those because adding 0 would not increment your sum in any way. There should be a where clause where hired = 1 in your count query.

```
select tasker_id, count(hired) as count_hired
from test.test
where hired = 1
group by tasker_id
order by count_hired;
```